# Find the top two items('Stage Gate" type Int) per group("GUID")

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I have already sorted by group/"GUID". And I want to pick only the top 2 "Stage Gate" per GUID.

I tried:

```
df.groupby('GUID')['Stage Gate'].nlargest(2)
```

but I am getting the same error:  Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object

```
obj = dataProcess(df)
obj.df.sort_values(by=['GUID','Stage Gate'], ascending=False).apply(lambda d: d.nlargest(2))
```

Comment: pls give us sample data and expected result. thanks.

Comment: You can't take nlargest over mixed types/ strings. Cast to int/float if the column is numeric

Comment: "Stage Gate" is of type int

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `sort_values` + `tail`

```
df.sort_values('Stage Gate').groupby('GUID').tail(2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to rearrange the sort and groupby.

`df.groupby('GUID').apply(lambda d: d.sort_values('Stage Gate', ascending=False).head(2))`